# Proof for embedded composition of PRG's

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

I have two secure pseudorandom generators, $G_1 : S\rightarrow R, G_2 : R\rightarrow T$. Now I need to prove that the PRG $G_3(s) = G_2(G_1(s))$ is secure.
I figured that I would construct two separate attack games, and assume the existence of an adversary $A$ that can distinguish the output of $G_3$ from a truly random string with a non-negligible advantage. This $A$ would then be used as a subroutine for the adversary $B$, which will mimic $G_3$.

From here I constructed a game that I believe works to challenge $G_1$ as follows: 
experiment 0: truly random 
$s$ is assigned a random value from seed space $S$. $s$ is then sent to the challenger $B$ which computes $G_2(s)$ and sends to $A$. $B$ then outputs whatever $A$ outputs. 
experiment 1: pseudorandom 
The above process is repeated again, however the challenger assigns $s$ randomly from $S$, and then assigns $r = G_1(s)$, which is then sent to $B$.

I am slightly lost, however, on how to continue this same idea to challenge $G_2$. My intuition is that it could possibly be challenged by simply sending a random string and a pseudorandom string encrypted with $G_2$ for each respective experiment. However, the concept of embedded PRG's is new to me so I have some slight confusion around the topic. I also apologize for any misuse of terminology in the title.